# Downloading videos from dnatube.com

Tags: applications

How can i download videos on my android mobile from dnatube.com ? After signing in when Ic click on dowload video button it shows "We are sorry, currently we are not allowed to give any permission for download due to copyright issues."
Is there any apps or online site which can capture videos from this site, youtube downloading ideas are not working.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Two popular apps are **TubeMate** (as zamin suggested) and **VidMate**. They can download videos from all popular video hosting websites. You won't find them in Play Store due to some copyright issues. Sites like YouTube, DailyMotion, Youku etc are provided as speed dials so you have to manually enter *dnatube.com*  in address bar. Comment if not working.

Comment: You can use Tubemate. it is the great app for youtube download. you can download tubemate [from here](http://tubemated.com).